# JavaScript not executing in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, execute

So I've begun learning HTML/CSS/JavaScript and came across this issue while trying to make an exceedingly simple version of rock-paper-scissors. I believe that the code works fine, but I can't check because **it refuses to execute.** I have looked extensively for answers on the internet, but can't seem to find any. *I have very little experience in JavaScript*, I am currently learning it off of [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) but I think that resource may be outdated as [other websites](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) appear to have conflicting syntax. In short, **what am I doing wrong, and which website has it right?**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>R,P,S!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function whole(){
            function game(play){
                if (play="yes"){
                    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
                    var computerChoice = Math.random();
                    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
                        computerChoice = "rock";}
                    else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
                        computerChoice = "paper";}
                    else {
                        computerChoice = "scissors";
                    }
                    function compare(choice1,choice2){
                        if (choice1==choice2){
                            compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
                        }
                        if (choice1=="rock"){
                            if (choice2=="scissors"){
                                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Rock wins";
                            }
                            else{
                                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Paper wins";
                            }
                        }
                        if (choice1=="paper"){
                            if (choice2=="rock"){
                                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Paper wins";
                            }
                            else{
                                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Scissors win";
                            }
                        }
                        if (choice1=="scissors"){
                            if (choice2=="paper"){
                                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Scissors win";
                            }
                            else{
                                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Rock wins";
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
                }
                else{
                    document.writeln("<p>Thanks for playing! This was made by Alex</p>";)
                }
            }
            var start = prompt ("Do you want to play?","Yes");}
    </script>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">
    <h1>JavaScript on a webpage? This is madness!</h1>
    <h2>Madness? THIS... IS... HTML!!!!</h2>
    <button onclick="whole()">Try it out!</button>
    <p id="result">Who won?</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit: It appears that Codecademy's glossary agrees with other websites, they just haven't gotten around to editing their lessons yet.*

**Edit: Here's my final little code for it. Enjoy its simplicity!*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>R,P,S!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function whole(){
            function game(play){
                if (play=="Yes"||play=="yes"){
                    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
                    var computerChoice = Math.random();
                    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
                        computerChoice = "rock";}
                    else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
                        computerChoice = "paper";}
                    else {
                        computerChoice = "scissors";
                    }
                    function compare(choice1,choice2){
                        if (choice1==choice2){
                            alert("It was a tie!");
                            game("yes");
                        }
                        if (choice1=="rock"){
                            if (choice2=="scissors"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="You win. Rock crushes scissors.";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="";
                            }
                            else{
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Paper smothers rock.";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                            }
                        }
                        else if (choice1=="paper"){
                            if (choice2=="rock"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="You win. Paper smothers rock.";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="";
                            }
                            else{
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Scissors cut paper.";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                            }
                        }
                        else if (choice1=="scissors"){
                            if (choice2=="paper"){
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="You win. Scissors cut paper.";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="";
                            }
                            else{
                                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="";
                                document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="You lose. Rock crushes scissors.";
                                document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Very funny. Now do it right.");
                            game("yes");
                        }
                    };
                    compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML="Well alrighty then.";
                    document.getElementById("loss").innerHTML="";
                    document.getElementById("win").innerHTML="";
                }
            }
            var start = prompt ("Do you want to play?","Yes");
            game(start);}
    </script>
    <style>
        body{
            text-align:center;
        }
        #messages{
            font-size:20px;
            color: #00246B;
        }
        #win{
            color: #29A329;
            font-size:18px;
        }
        #loss{
            color:#CC0000;
            font-size:18px;
        }
        a{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:black;
        }
        a:hover{
            font-size:125%;
            color:#B20000;
        }
        button{
            font-size:21px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://youtu.be/T8r3cWM4JII">
    <h1>JavaScript on a webpage? This is madness!</h1>
    <h2>Madness? THIS... IS... HTML!!!!</h2>
    </a>
    <button onclick="whole()">Try it out!</button>
    <p id="messages">Who won?</p>
    <p class="result"><span id="loss"></span><span id="win"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is happening?

Comment: The JavaScript isn't executing when I press the button.

Comment: You should open up your browser's development console, and check to see if there are any error messages. for example have a look at 'This was made by Alex</p>";)'

Comment: Your function doesn't do anything except ask if you want to play.

Comment: Ah. I apparently have an unexpected "}". That should be fun to find.

Comment: Try doing `alert("Hello world");` as the first line inside whole(). Do you get an alert box?

Comment: Your browser (assuming you have a normal one) should inform you on the line number of the error, in my console its telling me to look at line 49, and assuming you have a text editor that displays line numbers, you should be able to find it relatively easy.

Comment: No I don't. Apparently it's not counting whole() as defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is syntatically wrong. put semicolon after paranthesis.

```
else {
    document.writeln("<p>Thanks for playing! This was made by Alex</p>");
}
```

Now call the function game inside the closure at the end of function whole.

ie

```
function() whole(){ 
   function game(play) {
      // your logic
   }

   var start = prompt("Do you want to play?", "Yes");

   game(start);
}
```

Your game logic is error-prone. recheck your logic.

You are calling the function compare recursively infinitely when `choice1 == choice2`

just comment the line

```
if(choice1 == choice2) {
    // compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
}
```

it will work

Comment: again the comparison operator is '==' not '='.. inside function game change if(play = "yes") to play == "yes"

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. And I'm aware that the game isn't very good. That comparison only executes if there is a tie. I'll add fall-backs to it later, this was just to test out integration of JS in HTML.

Comment: Dud, i said when there is a tie, your current statement calls the function compare recursively indefenitely. There occurs a stack overflow and the interpretor exits

Comment: Ah, okay. That was supposed to be `game()` rather than `compare(userChoice, computerChoice)` anyways. Thanks for calling my attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your code:

Assignment operator in `if` statement:

```
if (play="yes")
```

This just assigns the string `"yes"` to the variable `play`. You should use a comparison operator:

if (play === "yes")

Misplaced semi-colon:

```
document.writeln("<p>Thanks for playing! This was made by Alex</p>";)
```

Should be:

```
document.writeln("<p>Thanks for playing! This was made by Alex</p>");
```

Comment: Already stated, but thanks anyways! Also, isn't the comparison operator "=="?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Oh okay. So both work in this instance. Didn't know that even existed, thanks for showing me.